# How To Deploy Third party software on Azure app service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET website that I am deploying to an Azure app service, which requires the Access Database Engine to be installed.  I have included the accessdatabaseengine.exe file and also added install.cmd.  In install.cmd file I have:

```
AccessDatabaseEngine.exe /passive.
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.  What am I missing?  What is the correct way to install a 3rd party binary in an Azure app service?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install arbitrary software when running on Azure App Service. Generally, you cannot make any machine level changes (e.g. registry changes).

For most apps, that is not an issue. But if that is a requirement for you, you will need to use an alternative offering, like Cloud Service or VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the [Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255), you are probably trying to query something using OleDb.  If that's the case, send that code back to the 90's where it belongs, and rework your code to use something a little more modern, like [ClosedXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML), which will come neatly along with your website in a NuGet package.